# US J1 visa -- Received email to submit passport but status is still refused

Tags: usa, visa, j-visa

I applied for US J1 visa some time ago. After the interview I was given a 221g form to submit some documents which I did. Now, I have received an email from the US embassy that my case has been processed with the advice to submit my passport.

However, when I checked my visa status online, it still says "Refused" with a recent  adjudication data.

If the visa status is still refused as per latest adjudication, why they asked for passport?

Comment: Perhaps they require your passport in order to update the status?